# If M is an $n\times n$ complex matrix, then $R(M)=(N(M^*))^T.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Consider the following statements :

$(1) :$ If M is an $n\times n$  complex matrix, then $R(M)=(N(M^*))^\perp.$
where $R(M)$ is the range space of $M$ and $N(M^*)$ is the nullity of $M^*=$ where $M^*=$conjugate transpose of $M$.

$(Q) :$ There exists a unitary matrix with an eigenvalue $λ$ such that $|λ| <1$.

Which of the following are true:

$Q$ is false since all eigenvalues of a unitary matrix have unit modulus .

**I am stuck in $P$** :
Let $y\in R(M)$ then $y=Mx$. But now to show that $M^*y=0$ .Please help

Comment: For the first question, instead try to prove that $R(M)^T = (N(M^*))$. Now, if $y \in R(M)^T$,  then $\langle y,Mx \rangle = 0$ for all $x$, so $\langle M^* y , x\rangle = 0$ for all $x$, so $M^* y = 0$. Similarly, the other way follows.

Comment: It looks like it should be a $\perp$ instead of a $T$.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: It is never good to be stuck in P.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to show that ${\cal R} M \subset (\ker M^*)^\bot $.

Suppose $y = Mx \in {\cal R} M$, and $z \in \ker M^*$, then
$\langle y, z \rangle = \langle Mx , z \rangle = \langle x , M^* z \rangle = \langle x , 0 \rangle = 0$.

Comment: Thanks,, for pointing the mistake!!